# Filter PivotTable on date range with blank rows showing

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a table of data that looks like this:

```
Created   Severity   Tickets Submitted
11/17/17  High       1
11/28/17  High       1
12/3/17   High       1
12/4/17   High       1
12/27/17  High       1
1/2/17    High       1
1/7/17    High       1
11/15/17  Low        1
11/16/17  Low        1
11/27/17  Low        3
12/11/17  Low        4
12/15/17  Low        1
12/19/17  Low        2
1/1/17    Low        1
1/4/17    Low        1
```

I'm trying to create a PivotTable that will return the data for each day, including the days with 0 values.

I've gotten to the point where I right clicked > Field Settings > Layout & Print > Show items with no data, which worked to show blank lines. However, now I have rows for January 1, 2017 to December 31, 2018.

I've tried filtering the rows on year/month in the PivotTable Fields window to only show November 2017 - January 2018, but it still shows me January 2017, and November and December 2018.

Is there any way to hide the specific month/year combinations? Alternatively, is it possible to only show the months that have values on at least one day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, right after I created the bounty, I discovered my answer.

Since I was using a PivotChart, I right clicked the chart and picked "Select data." I then clicked the "Hidden and Empty Cells" button in the bottom left corner, then picked "Zero"

That solved my problem completely.